# Spring MVC: Bean property is not readable or has an invalid getter method Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and I am having a problem in my application, I have been trying to populate a dropdown box with information from my database but I keep getting an error in the JSP, I get all the information in the controller but I cannot show it in the view, I have found similar cases in the site but none has an answer that I can use.

I keep getting the same error no matter what I try, the exception is the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'nombreEstado' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'nombreEstado' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:716)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:149)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:194)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:141)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
```

Right now I have this method in my controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("estados")
public List<Estado> obtenerEstados(){
    logger.debug("buscando todos los estados");

    for (int i = 0; i < this.estadoBo.obtenerEstados().size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(this.estadoBo.obtenerEstados().get(i).getNombreEstado());
    }

    return this.estadoBo.obtenerEstados();
}
```

I used the cycle just to see if the values were coming right from the database

And the JSP

```
<form:form modelAttribute="estados">
    <form:select path="nombreEstado" id="nombreEstado">
        <form:option value="">Estado: </form:option>
        <c:forEach items="${estados.getNombreEstado}" var="estado">
            <form:option value="${estado}">${estado}</form:option>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
```

I get the error in the line of the select path = "nombreEstado"

I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help will be welcomed

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsp stayed like this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="searchForm">
                <form:select path="nombreEstado" id="nombreEstado">
                    <form:option value="">Estado: </form:option>
                    <c:forEach items="${estados}" var="estado">
                        <form:option value="${estado}">${estado}</form:option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
```

I removed from items the getEstado property and from the controller I did the following changes:

```
@ModelAttribute("estados")
public List<String> obtenerEstados(){
    logger.debug("buscando todos los estados");

    int cantidadEstados = this.estadoBo.obtenerEstados().size();        
    ArrayList<String> estadoLista = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadEstados; i++) {
        estadoLista.add(this.estadoBo.obtenerEstados().get(i).getNombreEstado());           
    }               
    return estadoLista;             
}
```

and this is where I had the problem:

```
@ModelAttribute("estados")
public List<String> obtenerEstados(){
    logger.debug("buscando todos los estados");

    int cantidadEstados = this.estadoBo.obtenerEstados().size();        
    ArrayList<String> estadoLista = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadEstados; i++) {
        estadoLista.add(this.estadoBo.obtenerEstados().get(i).getNombreEstado());           
    }               
    return estadoLista;             
}
```

I added the attribute searchForm to the model with the new bean object and now it works fine